# Default sending all mails from the one account on Outlook 2007

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, outlook, outlook-2007

I have two email accounts configured on my outlook 2007. One account is connecting to my exchange server which is the default I have another account connecting to my gmail.

I want to by default send or reply all the emails that I receive on my gmail account through my exchange server account only.

When I try replying to the email that I receive from the gmail account it gets defaulted to the same (gmail account). I need to manually change it to exchange server account. I want that to be changed to exchange server account by default for all the mails that I send or reply to.

I don't want to do the manual process mentioned below in steps:

Step 1: In the message window, click Account.

Step 2: Click the account that you want to use.

Is there a way to set the exchange server account for sending and replying to all emails on outlook irrespective of the number of accounts that I have on outlook. I have my outlook installed on a windows 2003 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing sounds like forwarding a copy of all GMail emails to your Exchange account. That way you have just the Exchange inbox to worry about, and when you reply it will always be from Exchange.

Also, in GMail you can setup incoming email to auto-archive itself (that is, the GMail archive option, I'm not referring to Outlook's "Auto-archive" feature) so you can search for it in GMail if you need the original copy, but you don't have to worry archiving your email twice - once in GMail and once in your Exchange account.

Can I also ask why you have two accounts? There may be an alternate solution based on your use case.